# Hosting a server when behind ISP's router

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, port, bittorrent

No one in the internet seems to never adress this problem, idk why.
But, my situation looks sorta like this:

Me -- My router -- ISP's router -- Internet

My question isn't strictly "How" I can host a server in this situation, but "Why" I can't do it, even though (for example) my BitTorrent Client can open some ports and use them even though I don't have port forwarding enabled for him, or anyone else.

Comment: Very likely the ISP does carrier grade NAT in its internal network (you are **not** directly connected to "the internet" with the "ISP's router"), so you'd need the equivlane tof port forwarding on the ISP's internal routers. And ISP's don't do that, unless you pay them for it (which means a more expensive business contract with a static IPv4 address).

Comment: Why do you think so? Almost everyone has ISP-issued routers, that alone doesn't indicate CGNAT.

Comment: What problem are you encountering? How are the routers connected (LAN/WAN)? Can the ISP's router do port-forwarding (what model)?